# Is it possible to feature a meta question on the main site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A perceived problem with the contest is it doesn't have enough visibility. This could be addressed if it were possible for meta questions to be featured on the main site.

Ideally, such a question would show up in the "Hot" questions section.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up to 3 meta posts can be featured on the sidebar of the main site at any time.  Mods can adjust this at will using a "featured" tag.

Comment: Please note that these do not show up on mobile. So, the solution doesn’t work for some % of users.

Comment: Another problem with the sidebar is it's easy to ignore.